# Wildfly CertificateRoles Login Module and UTF-8 encoded rolesProperties file

Tags: java-ee-7, wildfly-10

For a Java EE 7 web application we are using SSL/TLS client-cert authentication
provided by Wildfly login module.

SSL realm is properly configured with adequate truststore and keystore files on the transport level authentication is successfull, but role mapping cannot map roles as it should based on certificate subject DN for some certificates.

These certificates have cyrillic characters in subject DN which are UTF-8 encoded.

How to configure CertificatesRoles login module to treat rolesProperties file as UTF-8 encoded file?

When I set file.encoding=UTF-8 subject DN from certificate is properly read, but string from roles file is not (i checked twice, it is UTF-8 encoded).

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of Properties class implementation. This class supports ISO 8859-1 encoding. Solution is to encode UTF-8 encoded file as ISO 8859-1 encoded file by using native2ascii tool provided in Java SDK or JRE.